# Multiple facebook post via jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, facebook

I'm trying to post multiple `facebook post` on a page by using `jQuery`. So far I am getting success to post first `facebook post` but not able to post another.

**What is happening?**

facebook post embed url is

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div><script>
(function(d, s, id)
 { 
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return; 
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;  
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";    
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }
(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/ClashofClans/posts/1104473549576967:0" data-width="500">
<div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/ClashofClans/posts/1104473549576967:0">
<p>The update is finally here!!! Maintenance will start soon! Read all that&#039;s new: http://supr.cl/UpdateNotes
</p>
Posted by 
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/ClashofClans">Clash of Clans</a> on&nbsp;
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/ClashofClans/post/1104473549576967:0">Wednesday, July 1, 2015</a>
</blockquote>
</div>
</div>
```

When I append this `URL` directly to `DIV`, it calls an iframe and then complete `facebook post` data binds on `DOM`. It works very well but next time `Iframe` is not loading on the DOM. In console first time I found an APP error ie `Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.`. I tried with correct `AppId` but not succeed. Below is my code what I've tried so far

```
$("input").blur(function ()
 {
   $('div').html($(this).val());
   //$(this).val() is facebook post URL shown above
 })
```

Will anyone please suggest me the correct way of doing that ?

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking, resp. where the actual problem lies. You are not putting the code that embeds and initializes the JS SDK multiple times on the same page, right?

Comment: please check this demo url i have created
http://dothejob.in/fb.php

Comment: You should only embed the JS SDK once, not every time. And it only checks the document for elements to render into social plugins once on initialization; if you want it to parse additional elements after that, you need to call `FB.XFBML.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. It factors when the code is loaded. The answer was created using this source [Working with asynchronously loaded javascript](http://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/working-with-asynchronously-loaded-javascript) You can wrap the getLoginStatus call in a loop if you will.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <input type="button" id="send" value="Send" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function facebookReady() {
                FB.init({
                    appId      : '1521775134725984',
                    xfbml      : true,
                    status   : true,
                    cookie     : true,
                    version    : 'v2.1'
                });
                $(document).trigger("facebook:ready");
            }

            if(window.FB) {
                facebookReady();
            } else {
                window.fbAsyncInit = facebookReady;
            }
        });

        $(document).on("facebook:ready", function() {

            $("#send").on("click", function() {
                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                    if (response.status === 'connected') {
                        var body = $("#message").val();
                        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
                            if (!response || response.error) {
                                alert('Error occured');
                            } else {
                                alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        FB.login(function(){
                        }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```